# Inspecting model values when stubbing it's save method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, sinon

I'm trying to test some logic inside a callback without connecting to a database. To do this, I need to stub the model's save method. I do, however, still need to inspect model values that change as part of the logic.

The logic:

```
// check if user exists with facebook or google account
User.findOne({ $or: [{'facebook.email': email}, {'google.email': email}] }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    else {
        // create new user
        if (!user) {
            user = new User();
        }

        // add the local account
        user.local.email = email; // <--
        user.local.password = User.generateHash(password);

        // create a new token for the local account
        user.local.token = User.createAccessToken(email);

        // save
        user.save(function(err, user) {
            if (err) cb(err);
            return cb(false, user); // <-- HOW DO I TEST that user.local.email == email inside this callback?
        });
    }
});
```

My test looks like this:

```
it('should create new user if email not in database', function(done) {
        var email = 'test@test.com';
        sinon.stub(User, 'findOne').yields(false, null);
        sinon.stub(User.prototype, 'save') // <-- how to stub this correctly?
        userService.localSignup(email, '123123', function(err, user) {
            assert.instanceOf(user, User);
            assert.equal(user.local.email, email);
            assert.isNotNull(user.local.password);
            return done();
        });
    });
```

Maybe these nested callbacks are a bad pattern?

Comment: Still looking for a nice solution for this...